# How to transform datettime to Solr format in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, solr, iso

How to transform this:

`'2020-01-21 12:23:54'`

to this (solr format):

`'2020-01-21T12:23:54.625Z'`  ??

If not possible, how does one directly get the dates (e.g. modified date) of files in Python directly in the Solr format (shown above) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime` to format dates as required by Solr (that is [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)), adding the 'Z' explicitly since `isoformat()` function does not include any timezone information :

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.utcnow().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z'
```

Starting with a given date string, you can parse it with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) then convert it to iso (assuming the date is already in utc) :

```
d = datetime.strptime('2020-01-21 12:23:54', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').isoformat() + 'Z'
```

You should set `timespec='seconds'` if you don't need more precision (Solr will ignore fractions beyond milliseconds).